# Trouble passing variable through href php

Tags: php

In my php script I want to pass a variable through href.
This is my code:

Script1.php

```
<td><a href="#top_opps?name=david" role="button" data-toggle="modal" ><?php echo $row['listings_views']; ?></a>  </td>
```

But when I want to get the variable in the other script

Script2.php

```
<?php $var=$_GET['name']; 
echo $var; ?>
```

It shows me a error message. What could be my error?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You cannot pass GET variables in a hashtag link.  Doesn't work.  GET variables are only available if you cause the page to actually load with those GET variables in the URL string.

Comment: @K3nel31: that's simply not correct.

Comment: You should also avoid short_open_tags as they are off by default (since PHP Version X). [Here is the link to the w3c page describing the URL patterns in addition to Guillaume Lehezee's answer](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html)

Comment: @K3rnel31 1. Every request to a server is GET by default and can actually have parameters. 2. OP uses HTML5, you suggested XHTML syntax in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
<td><a href="?name=david#top_opps" role="button" data-toggle="modal" ><?php echo $row['listings_views']; ?></a>  </td>
```

Comment: Well now there is no error but I do not get the variable yet.

Comment: And what about if the href is : "Script2.php?name=david#top_opps"

Comment: No changes ... other suggestion please